# How to use .NET reflection to determine method return type (including void) and parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, void

how to know the number and type of parameters?

how to know the return type?

how to check whether the return type is void?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`MethodInfo.ReturnType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.returntype.aspx) to determine the return type, and [`MethodBase.GetParameters()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx) to find out about the parameters. (`MethodInfo` derives from `MethodBase`, so once you've got the `MethodInfo` via `Type.GetMethod` etc, you can use both `ReturnType` and `GetParameters()`.)

If the method is `void`, the return type will be `typeof(void)`:

```
if (method.ReturnType == typeof(void))
```

Comment: how to check the voidness? and how to get MethodBase given a MethodInfo? thanks!

Comment: @Louis: MethodInfo derives from MethodBase, and you use `typeof(void)` to check for voidness.

Comment: will this do?
`if(method.ReturnType.Equals(typeof(void)))`

Comment: @Louis: You could do that, but I would just use ==. I'll edit to demonstrate:

Comment: I didn't realise System.Void was an actual type - does this mean methods with void return types have actual values returned in IL?

Comment: @Chris: Nope - it's sort of a placeholder type, really. It's useful to have a type representing the void precisely for things like ReturnType.