# How can I find object type and name of the executing function?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, reflection, clr

Consider the following code:

```
class A
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        string thisFunction = // get the name of the executing function (Foo)
        string thisType = // get the name of the object type (A)
        Log.PrintLog(thisFunction, thisType);
    }
}

public static class Log
{
    public static void PrintLog(string function, string type)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Call from function {0}, type {1}", function, type);
    }
}
```

How can I find name of the executing function and object type?
Any other solution except using [CallerFilePath] and [CallerMemberName]?

Comment: Tell us your target .NET version.

Comment: [You may want to refer answer on this page][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456994/how-to-use-net-reflection-to-determine-method-return-type-including-void-and

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the method that called the current method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)

Comment: Anyone who wants [CallerTypeName] to exist please vote on https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/87

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can create a StackTrace anywhere you want:

```
StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
```

Then it's just about cycling through the StackFrames:

```
StackFrame[] sf = st.GetFrames();

// in case your PrintLog has overloads or recursions
//  it may appear several times in the stack
string ownName = "PrintLog"; 
MethodInfo curMethod = null;
for(int i = 0; i < sf.Length; i++) {
     curMethod = sf[i].GetMethod();
     if(ownName != curMethod.Name)
         break;
}
Console.WriteLine("Call from function {0}, type {1}", 
                  curMethod.Name, 
                  curMethod.DeclaringType.Name);
```

You could even identify the class and parameters (you have the MethodInfo object to play around with)

Personally I put the Time TID caller class+type+name into my logging context.

---

As I understand you wanted to parse the function name and type to the `PrintLog` function. Thats just messy!

The beauty of this approach is, that you don't have to do that. You can retreive the name and type of the *caller* **within** the `PrintLog` method.

Comment: The solution through `StackFrame` not proven, because the compiler can optimize (inline) some methods.

Comment: So what would be **your** suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

```
 string thisFunction = Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name; 
 string thisType = this.GetType().Name;
```

Comment: Doesn't this return the name of the current -, namly the `PrintLog` method?

Comment: No, it will return the name of the currently executing method.

Comment: Exacatly! The OP want's to put this code into the `PrintLog` method, which would be *currently executing* at the time of this query. So you won't get the caller will you?

Comment: @MrPaulch where did you see OP wants to put this into `PrintLog` ? I can't see it? the `function` and `type` are just parameters.he wants to get the name of the method and type then pass them to `PrintLog` method (in the **Foo**)

Comment: Sorry you are right. He didn't. I am just thinking, this portion *belongs* into the `PrintLog` method

Answer (score 2):

Int .Net4.5 you have the [CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Allows you to obtain the method or property name of the caller to the
>   method.

Also you may try with:

```
new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
```

Also check this interesting link answer:- [Can you use reflection to find the name of the currently executing method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method)

Comment: The solution through `StackFrame` not proven, because the compiler can optimize (inline) some methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with the path rather than the type name:

```
class A
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Log.PrintLog();
    }
}

public static class Log
{
    public static void PrintLog([CallerMemberName] string function = null,
                                [CallerFilePath] string path = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Call from function {0}, file {1}", function, path);
    }
}
```

For instance methods you might choose to use `GetType()` to obtain the current type - this is not possible for static methods, though. So you could use:

```
public static void PrintLog(object obj = null,
       [CallerMemberName] string function = null,
       [CallerFilePath] string path = null)
{
    string name = obj == null ? path : obj.GetType().Name;
    Console.WriteLine("Call from function {0}, name {1}", function, name);
}
```

with:

```
Log.PrintLog(this);
```

Comment: @HamletHakobyan actually, not quite - it is a **compiler** feature, not a runtime feature. If you are using the later C# compiler, you can use this feature on older frameworks simply by declaring the attribute yourself in the correct namespace.

Comment: I.e syntactical sugar? Didn't know. Thanks. But, from other site, again IMO, the compiler is part of framework, then we can said since .net 4.5 :)

Comment: That was my original solution, but [CallerFilePath] does not show type name in a nice way.

Comment: @XyiTebe do you see what I'm doing in the second example with `obj` ? But yes, it is a shame that there is no `[CallerTypeName]`

Comment: What if the class is static?

Comment: @XyiTebe I discussed that in the answer; you would just have to settle for the filename, assuming you don't want to use `typeof(...)`

Comment: @MarcGravell and anyone else interested in [CallerTypeName] please vote on https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/87

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456994/how-to-use-net-reflection-to-determine-method-return-type-including-void-and) you may use `MethodInfo`class to find return type as `MethodInfo.ReturnType`